# i dont understand how the devise admin model work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, admin

I am building a rails app, and i want users and a Admin (me), but i dont understand how the devise admin model work, because if i have have a admin model, cant anyone just go to the link (/admins/sign_up) and sign_up as a admin on my site?

I have already tried to look around on the internet but i just cant seem to find an answer.

If you can explain to me how i can get over this problem, i would love you :D

Thank you
- Peace

Comment: Please edit your question and delete the sentence asking for a tutorial, or this question will likely be closed as a request for an off-site resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `rake routes | grep 'admin'` you will see that there is no route like admin/sign_up. The admin user should be created on rails console or within the admin.

When you install devise (with the migrations and all) it creates for you a default admin user with email: "admin@example.com" and password: "password".

You should login with it to create your real admin user and them delete this default one.

And here is an excellent devise tutorial: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/how-to-use-devise-in-rails-for-authentication :)

Comment: If it solved your problem, please select my answer as the correct to help other people with the same problem find the solution :)

Comment: Yeah thanks, i am still kinda new to stack overflow :D